# jsoncpp compilation error for Json::Value type

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

This is the schema:

```
{
"definitions": {
    "properties": {
        "Count": {
            "type": [
                "number",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}
I want to read members in "type"

I tried to attempt in many ways, e.g.

```
if(val["definitions"]["properties"]["Count"]["type"][0] == "number" and 
(val["definitions"]["properties"]["Count"]["type"][1] == "null"))
{
    //code here
}
```

This leads to the following error

> error : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Json::LogicError' what(): in Json::Value::operator: requires arrayValue Aborted (core dumped)

And for this piece of code

```
if (val["definitions"]["properties"]["Count"]["type"][0].isMember("number") and 
(val["definitions"]["properties"]["Count"]["type"][0].isMember("null"))){
    //code here
}
```

I get

> error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Json::LogicError'
>   what(): in Json::Value::find(key, end, found): requires objectValue or nullValue Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: `Count` is written using an uppercase C in your JSON and lowercase c in your code - is that intentional?

Comment: "Count" vs "count"

Comment: That is mistake while drafting here. Sorry, Now I have modified here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const Json::Value obj=val["definitions"]["properties"]["count"]["type"];
    if (std::find(obj.begin(),obj.end(),"string")!=obj.end() and 
 std::find(obj.begin(),obj.end(),"null")!=obj.end()){
    // code here;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is right... your json is wrong... JsonCpp needs the quotes for "definitions" and you can't have extra commas after the last item in an array or object.

just change it to:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "properties": {
            "Count": {
                "type": [
                    "number",
                    "null"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

;-)

Comment: Actually the JSON code presented here is part of some valid JSON schema (DMTF Redfish schemas). The issue is with code itself.

Comment: Change the JSON, try it by yourself... remove the commas and put quotes. It will start to work.

Comment: That is what I dont understand...everything seems correct....but it was showing the error.